# I can't run "drush core-cli"

Tags: drush

I have installed drush on crunchbang linux and while most of the drush commands are working, I can't get core-cli to work. Running `drush @dev core-cli` returns this error message.

> The drush command 'core-cli' could not be found.  Run[error] `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.

I initially tried installing Drush via APT; when core-cli didn't work, I tried getting it via PEAR, but it's doing the same thing.  With the version I got from pear(5.8) `drush self-update` works, when it didn't with the APT version, an earlier release.

I've made sure that my user has full rights to the /usr/share/php/drush folder.

Comment: Are you sure that drush core-cli exists? If yes, what does it do and from where did you get that command? Is there any module that provides that drush command?

Answer (score 3):

`drush core-cli` has been removed in Drush 5.

> Drush 5 supports bash completion which is much more native and superior to the old core-cli command, which has been removed.

For more information, see [Core-cli command removed in favor of Bash completion](http://drupal.org/node/1406050).